# Why does Git execute hooks from an other repository?

Tags: git, githooks

With this MWE Git executes hooks in a the wrong repository (`A`):

```sh
# Make simple repo
git init "/tmp/A" && cd "/tmp/A" || exit 1

# Make hook to demonstrate the problem
mkdir -p ".git/hooks" &&
    echo "echo 'EXECUTED!!!'" >.git/hooks/reference-transaction &&
    chmod +x ".git/hooks/reference-transaction" &&
    git clone -c core.hooksPath=".git/hooks" --template= "https://github.com/gabyx/Githooks.git" /tmp/Githooks
```

Results in

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/test/tmp/A/.git/
Cloning into 'Githooks'...
EXECUTED!!!
EXECUTED!!!
EXECUTED!!!
EXECUTED!!!
```

Which is totally weird: I expect `git clone` to execute the hook in `/tmp/Githooks/.git/hooks` because from

[`core.hooksPath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehooksPath)

> The path can be either absolute or relative. A relative path is taken as relative to the directory where the hooks are run (see the "DESCRIPTION" section of githooks[5]).

and further in [Doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) :

> Before Git invokes a hook, it changes its working directory to either $GIT_DIR in a bare repository or the root of the working tree in a non-bare repository.

Why is this, and is this a Bug which should be reported?

Comment: You override the "hooks path" for this command to the directory you created.  Right?  You told it not to use the normal location.

Comment: Yes, exactly thats what I did. Also this override is uncommon in almost all usecases (in my case its not) it results in some wrong behavior IMO

Comment: Then what's the problem?  It did exactly what you told it to do.  Why do you think it's a bug?

Comment: Why I use this: I wanna clone a repo and `core.hooksPath` might be set globally which I **must not use** and I also dont want to populate a template `--template=`. `core.hooksPath=.git/hooks` ensures GIT LFS installs its hooks, thats why I use it.

Comment: Fine, but you said this was "totally weird", and it looks to me like it operated correctly.

Comment: But, why did it? It uses the execution working dir (`/tmp/A`)  and appends `.git/hooks`. Is this really what it should do? If it would first (because it got a relative path `.git/hooks` ) apply the mentioned quote, and then append `.git/hooks` onto it, it would work more logically ... ?

Comment: So meaning: Any relative path is relative to the working dir of the execution: Thats also whats mentioned here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehooksPath

Comment: Right.  The hooks will be run in the root of the working tree, which is `/tmp/A`, and that's where it looks for `.git/hoks`.

Comment: Ah so, there are two things, "looking" for hooks, and "executing" hooks
which both have a working dir associated with...

Comment: I think its wrong. Eventhough I could be technically correct...

Comment: _so there are two things_ -- not at all.  In both cases, the base is `/tmp/A` -- the root of the working tree.

Comment: Hm.. not quite: When I change `git clone` with `cd "$(pwd)/.." && git clone ...` it will execute the hooks in `/tmp/Githooks/.git/hooks`....

Comment: *The root of the working tree in a non-bare repository*: -> Should be `/tmp/Githooks` IMO

Comment: No.  That just happens to be the source for your clone.  The working tree for THIS git command is `/tmp/A`.

Comment: Jeah, I understand. *A relative path is taken as relative to the directory where the hooks are run* But that is unclear. where are the hooks run then?

Comment: You said it up above.  "Before git invokes a hook, it changes its working directory to ... the root of the working tree."  That's the answer for both questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug.

The `git clone` command is kind of a special case, because it *makes a new Git repository*.  Subsequent operations should happen *in* this new repository.  Relative paths should probably be relative *to* the new repository.  However, there should be no hooks there unless the template provides them.

(It's not clear to me that a template can be a Git repository: the template should be a local file tree.)

As a general rule, it's unwise to run any hook that has not had a chance to be verified first.

This is one of those cases that will generate arguments.

Comment: There is GIT LFS involved as well ? I am not sure, it creates hooks as well. Maybe triggered from a filter?

Comment: Git-LFS uses clean and smudge filters rather than hooks (well, maybe in addition to hooks, I have never delved into the details).

Comment: Thats correct, but it uses also hooks to account for file locks and other stuff.